# Ballpark value for `--jobs` in `pg_restore` command

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm using [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) to restore a database to its original state for load testing. I see it has a `--jobs=number-of-jobs` option.

How can I get a ballpark estimate of what this value should be on my machine? I know this is dependent on a bunch of factors, e.g. machine, dataset, but it would be great to get a conceptual starting point.

I'm on a MacBook Pro so maybe I can use the number of physical CPU cores:

```
sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu
# 10
```

Comment: Just try different values and see what works. This process is probably not CPU bound. Using too high a value just causes more I/O contention, so there are diminishing returns at some point, and probably before you run out of cores to throw at the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no concurrent activity at all, don't exceed the number of parallel I/O requests your disk can handle. This applies to the `COPY` part of the dump, which is likely I/O bound. But a restore also creates indexes, which uses CPU time (in addition to I/O). So you should also not exceed the number of CPU cores available.

Comment: Any idea how I can get those values on my macbook pro? I think I can get the number of cpu cores using `sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu`